# Pass Username/Password to Authenticated Proxy VB.NET - SQL - Simple, but can't figure out

Tags: sql, vb.net, proxy

Have a simple windows form application (VB.net in VS 2013).

Has one time connection to a SQL database to verify activation key.

Works great, except when program is installed on a computer that requires an authenticated proxy.  Then get the 'not authenticated' error.

SQL connection:

```
 dbSource = "Initial Catalog=MySQLDatabse;Data Source=123.123.123.123;Persist Security  Info=True;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword"

 mySQLConn = New SqlConnection(dbSource)
 mySQLConn.Open()
 mySQLCmd = mySQLConn.CreateCommand
 mySQLCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ActKey='1234567'"
 'Rest of Sub Here
```

Have searched for solution, come up empty handed.

By default, when a user opens up a web browser (like for www.stackoverflow.com) on the client computer, proxy server authentication pops up and requests Username and Password.

Do I implement WebProxy?  with .Credentials?

Do I even need to have user enter credentials to access the database (since it's not thru HTTP), or can I just use default credentials in app.config file :

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in the app.config file before this way...

```
 <system.net>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true" />
    </settings>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://yourproxy"/>
    </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```